# About the color

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life

When I am reading my book keeping my head steady, everything is fine. But when I bend towards the right or left of the book, or the phone screen, things become darker (it happens more in phone screens). Why does this happen?

I also noticed that if a box of yellow color (maybe there are other colors too) is on the phone screen (for highlighting a text) and I bend similarly, it becomes completely black.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about how phone screens work not physics

Comment: Not so sure this is phone screens since books were mentioned. To me it sounds like an eye or optical nerve issue. Check if other people see the same thing under the same conditions.

Comment: May it be due to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law